# Add an icon to Internet Explorer pinned site on the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, icons

Is there a way to add an icon to a pinned Internet Explorer page on the task-bar? One of the sites I have pinned does not and it is very ugly and I have no idea what site it is because the icon is just a white square.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify the shortcuts. Simply, they are icons which you can modify their properties to change to an icon you prefer.

Here are more detailed instructions if you aren't familiar with how to do this; [How to Customize Your Windows 7 Taskbar Icons for Any App](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28847/how-to-customize-your-windows-7-taskbar-icons-for-any-app/).

Comment: This doesn't work for IE tabs.

Comment: That's strange, I was able to use an IE shortcut with mine. Sorry it doesn't work for you.

Comment: No problem. The only tabs I'm seeing in properties are General, Security, Details, and Previous Versions